# Spring-Boot Jackson Parsing Error While returning Basic Response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

Im trying to return only Basic ResponseEntity in my Application Noticing Jackson Parsing Error. When i do the same in sample Spring boot application , it works fine , not able to figure out what can be causing this issue.This is existing Application.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@Slf4j
@Tag(name = "Public Key")
public class PublicKeyController {

@PostMapping(value ="/checkraw")
public ResponseEntity<String>  getPostResp() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("test");
}
}
```

Error :

```
level":"ERROR","thread":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","message":"Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('test')\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]","stack_trace":"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('test')\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1455)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1081)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator.createFromString(ValueInstantiator.java:258)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:357)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:4229)\r\n\t... 77 common frames omitted\r\nWrapped by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('test')\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:4234)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:4175)\r\n\tat com.ocbc.ms.signature.advice.DigitalSigningControllerAdvice.beforeBodyWrite(DigitalSigningControllerAdvice.java:258)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyAdviceChain.processBody(RequestResponseBodyAdviceChain.java:141)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyAdviceChain.beforeBodyWrite(RequestResponseBodyAdviceChain.java:116)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:278)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat com.ocbc.ms.core.filter.AddHeaderToContextFilter.doFilter(AddHeaderToContextFilter.java:32)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat com.ocbc.ms.core.filter.ResponseHeaderSetterFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeaderSetterFilter.java:22)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat com.ocbc.ms.core.filter.MandatoryHeaderValidationFilter.doFilter(MandatoryHeaderValidationFilter.java:71)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat com.ocbc.ms.core.filter.InjectionSafeValidationFilter.doFilter(InjectionSafeValidationFilter.java:60)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat com.ocbc.ms.core.filter.MDCRequestFilter.doFilter(MDCRequestFilter.java:40)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat com.ocbc.ms.core.filter.MultiReadRequestFilter.doFilter(MultiReadRequestFilter.java:22)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat com.ocbc.ms.core.filter.ExceptionHandlerFilter.doFilterInternal(ExceptionHandlerFilter.java:27)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\r\n"}
```

If i use return custome object , it works fine as below

```
@PostMapping(value = "/checkraw")
 public DummyObject getPostResp() {
     DummyObject response = new DummyObject();
     return response ;
 }
```

below are the dependency

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- cmbp core framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cmbp.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>ms-lib-core</artifactId>
        <version>${ms-lib-core.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cmbp.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>ms-lib-connector-resttemplate</artifactId>
        <version>${ms-lib-connector-resttemplate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cmbp.ms</groupId>
        <artifactId>ms-lib-openapi</artifactId>
        <version>${ms-lib-openapi.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- misc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
        <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>${nimbus-jose-jwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-types-52.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        <version>${logstash-logback-encoder.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- For OCPS Check -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>${bcpkix-jdk15on.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>${bcpkix-jdk15on.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- For OCPS Check -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-collections.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-net.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-cli.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-pool2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For OCPS Check -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- added after removing ms-pom-security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-platform-launcher.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jeasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>easy-random-core</artifactId>
        <version>${easy-random-core.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
                <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Are you using `@RestController`?

Comment: Yes im using @RestController

Comment: what's your definition of `ResponseEntity`. It seems that `ResponseEntity` should have a constructor with string-argument.

Comment: can you please show me your entity

Comment: When you use `@RestController`, all response objects are automatically wrapped within`ResponseEntity`

Comment: @Prashant - yes very strange this does happen in this spring boot application.. can be issue with dependency or some spring level config

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/checkraw")
public String getPostResp() {
    return "test";
}
```

Spring Boot should take care of marshaling back the return value into a response.

Instead of @PostMapping have you tried with @GetMapping. That will most likely work.

Comment: Same Error Here As well

Comment: I cant find any filter or anything that may intercept the request

Comment: "Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('test')\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]"

Comment: Dheeraj, If possible can you share your imports. Thanks. Also I noticed that in the code snippet there is a 'z' character before the public key word of your class definition. I presume this is just a typo when pasting the code here, but you never know.

Comment: mp30028 - yes its typo - i have updated the dependency

Comment: For the Lombok dependency in the pom, the scope should be changed to provided. 
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

Also lombok needs to be setup. Follow the instructions here https://projectlombok.org/setup/overview based on your ide.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. This code was added not sure why it was implemented but was causing the issue. Thankyou for all your support.

```
public class ControllerAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {

@Override
public boolean supports(
@NonNull MethodParameter returnType,
 @NonNull Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
return true;
}

@Override
public Object beforeBodyWrite(
Object body,
 @NonNull MethodParameter parameter,
 @NonNull MediaType mediaType,
 @NonNull Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType,
 @NonNull ServerHttpRequest request,
 @NonNull ServerHttpResponse response) {
if (body == null
 || Primitives.allWrapperTypes().contains(body.getClass())
|| Primitives.allPrimitiveTypes().contains(body.getClass())
|| (body instanceof String && ((String) body).contains("openapi"))) {
return body;
 }

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 Map<String, Object> map =
mapper.convertValue(body, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
});

 if (map.containsKey(ERROR_CODE)
&& map.get(ERROR_CODE) != null
 && map.get(ERROR_CODE).toString().startsWith("AUTH-401")) {
List<String> apiKeyList = request.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
 if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(apiKeyList)) {
response.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, apiKeyList.get(0));
 }
}
return body;
}
```

Comment: Strange way to Authorize a user. Should this not be done via some filter (interceptor) overrides?

Comment: Agree Existing Code ...have to refactor